# How do you specify which browsers Sauce Labs should use when initiating tests from the Polymer CLI?

Tags: polymer, web-component-tester, polymer-cli, wct

I have a Polymer v1.7 element only project.

I have it set up with Travis CI and Sauce Labs which works great!

However, I would like to be able to initiate tests in specific browsers through Sauce Labs without having to tinker with my wct.conf.json file every time.

Polymer CLI's help output shows that you can specify browsers by using the `--sauce` flag but doesn't tell you what format is required:

`-s, --sauce string     Remote Sauce Labs browsers to run tests on, or 'default'`

Can anyone tell me how to specify the browsers? I imagine I need to tell it what platform, browser and version I need, just don't know how!

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the answer you are looking for. But I figured it might help.
We are using SauceLab and [Polymers web-componet-tester](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester)
Inside the wct.conf.json file you can specify the browsers SourceLab should use.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that. I was just hoping to be able fire off quick tests without tinkering with config files. Main reason being that if I add IE11 on any platform to wct.conf.json the tests start timing out on Travis CI when I push my code, meaning I then need to remove IE and recommit/push.